# How can I prove this operator is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be the normed space of all polynomials on $[0,1]$ such that $\| x \| = \max \limits _{t \in [0,1]} |x(t)|$ and we have the following operator $Tx(t)=x'(t)$. Prove this operator is not continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: because $X$ is a normed space, a linear map $T: X \to X$ is continuous if and only if it is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

For $n>1$, consider $x_n(t)=t^n$, then $Tx_n(t)=nx^{n-1}$, thus 
$$\Vert Tx_n(t)\Vert=n=n\Vert x_n(t)\Vert$$

hence $T$ is unbounded.